# How to synchronize two child fork process with shared memory and semaphores?

Tags: c, linux, fork, semaphore, shared-memory

I have to do tiny project in linux about sync and semaphores and I have some trouble...
The thing is I want to create two process, child 1 (PP1) and child 2 (PP2), PP1 reads data from file by parts (16 chars) and save them to shared memory which PP2 is using and save this chars to new file AFTER doing on them caezar cipher...

It almost works but I have some fear that it is not correct, cause it works while sleep() is there, without it, synchronize doesn't work.

File **tst** contains text:

> Blockquote
>   szesnasciebajtow bajtowszesnascie siaaaaalllla

Here is the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define SHM_SIZE 16

int main()
{
    int countToCipher,character, rozmiar=0,rd,i,des;
    char nazwaPliku[50];

    printf("Type file name \n");
    scanf("%s", nazwaPliku);

    if( access( nazwaPliku, F_OK ) != -1 ) {
        printf("Type key number: \n");
        scanf("%i", &countToCipher);
    } else {
        printf("File does not exist!");
        exit(0);
    }

    if( access( nazwaPliku, R_OK ) == -1 ) {
        printf("No permission!");
        exit(0);
    }

    FILE* fodczyt;
    fodczyt = fopen(nazwaPliku, "r");
    fseek(fodczyt,0,SEEK_END);
    rozmiar = ftell(fodczyt);

    int shmid,semid;
    key_t key;
    char *shm,*s;       

    if ((key = ftok(".", 'B')) == -1) 
        errx(1, "Error key!");

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0660)) < 0) {    
        perror("shmget");
        errx(2, "Error creatin shm!");
    }

    if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1){
        perror("shmat");
        errx(3, "Error connect shm");
    }               

    sem_t *sem1 = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*sem1),
                                PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,                                                      
                                MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (sem1 == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sem_init(sem1, 1, 1);

    if(fork()==0){
        //PP1
        int stop = 0,i;
        FILE *odczyt = fopen(nazwaPliku, "r"); 
        char ch;

        while(stop!=1){
            printf("\nPP1 waits\n");
            sem_wait(sem1);
            printf("PP1 enter\n");

            s=shm;

            for(i=0;i<SHM_SIZE+1;i++){
                ch = getc(odczyt);
                if(feof(odczyt)){
                    stop=1;
                    s[i]=EOF;
                    int j;
                    for(j=0;j<SHM_SIZE-i;j++) s[i]='\0';
                    break;
                }
                s[i]=ch;                        
            }
            sem_post(sem1);
            printf("PP1 exit\n");
            sleep(2);
        }
        fclose(odczyt);
        shmdt(shm);
    }

    if(fork()==0){
        //PP2
        int stop=0;
        char* odbior;
        sleep(1);

        des = open( "szyfr", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND,  0666 );
        while(stop!=1){
            printf("\nPP2 waits\n");
            sem_wait(sem1);
            printf("PP2 enter\n");

            odbior = shm;

            for (i = 0; i<SHM_SIZE; i++) {
                if(odbior[i]=='\0')
                {
                    stop=1;
                    break;
                }

                character = odbior[i];

                if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') {
                    character += (int)countToCipher;

                    if (character > 'z') {
                        character = character - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
                    }
                    odbior[i] = character;              
                }
                else if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z') {
                    character += (int)countToCipher;

                    if (character > 'z') {
                        character = character - 'A' + 'Z' - 1;
                    }
                    odbior[i] = character;
                }
            }
            write(des,odbior,SHM_SIZE);
            sem_post(sem1);
            printf("PP2 exit\n");
            sleep(2);
        }
        shmdt(shm);
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    sem_destroy(sem1);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the console output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS9EF.jpg)

Here is output in new file:

> Blockquote
>   taftobtdcbkupxtatjbbbbbmtaftobtdjfcbkupxcbkupxtaftobtdjftjbbbbbmmmmb(NULL)djf

Comment: I didn't check the synchronization code, but the formula for character rotation in case of lower case is wrong. Furthermore in upper case section you are checking `character > 'z'` instead of `character > 'Z'`.

Comment: To test the synchronization I suggest trying with CountToCipher = 0. In that case the same input string is expected.

Comment: Ok, its fine. Honestly I care about this sync most, but thanks.